# Jquery ui tab active tab background color not getting changed

Tags: css, jquery-ui-tabs

I am facing an issue in jquery ui tabs. I am trying to use the  #2980b9  as my actve tab background. when I click  a tab and make it active the chrome inspect element shows blow css class with #2980b9 as background but the color getting appered is different. What is the problem here?

```
        #planTab .ui-tabs-active    
   {
            border-color: #2980b9 !important;
            background: #2980b9 !important;   
   }
```

Comment: give `background:none !important` followed by your custom color...because they are using background image

Comment: It is background color used for background color

Comment: see closely or inspect it they are using background-image for active.

Comment: I did it for many time it is background-color they are using

Comment: `.ui-state-active {
    background: url("images/ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff_1x400.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    color: #212121;
    font-weight: normal;
}` check it out..better fiddle it

Answer (score 0):

Try below `CSS`

```
#planTab .ui-tabs-active:hover
{
    background-color : #2980b9;
}

#planTab .ui-tabs-active
{
    background-color : #333333;
}
```

You can replace the active color by actual color. presently I have given `#333333`.

Comment: Can you share the fiddle. It will be easier to fix it.